# Git Newbie: Work flow for a one person project

Tags: git, workflow

I'm learning to use git to manage my code for a small lab. 
Right now, I'm the only developer.

I have a repo setup and I've been committing locally and pushing to the origin.
I'm confused about when I should clone the repo. In fact, I'm confused about the workflow in general, especially when there's only one developer, no features to branch on yet, but I do have a working code base that I'd like to not keep breaking with minor commits.

I like to push my code at the end of the day to protect my work in-progress.

TIA

EDIT: clone should be checkout
EDIT2: perhaps check should = branch

Comment: `checkout` in git is used to get the source, e.g. from a branch. You checkout a branch when you want to work with it.

Comment: ah...yes....branch, then check out the branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have already setup a repo and pushed it to a remote, there is not currently any need to make another clone. The need for a `clone` would for instance occur when you want to continue your work on a new machine.

A classic branching strategy is described [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). There are scripting tools to support it [here](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow). However, it might be a bit over-engineered if you are a single developer working on a small lab.

However, if you have a stable code base that you want to avoid disturbing with minor commits, you should make liberal use of branches. Branching and merging is cheap and simple in git. Create a branch as soon as you start work on a feature. Commit your feature work to that branch. Merge the feature branch to master when stable. (Or `rebase` if you like a straight version history, since you are the sole developer it is completely safe).

Pushing daily sounds like an excellent idea.

Comment: Thank you...my terminology is still screwed up. Your answer is clarifying. In a way, any change that could break the code, is a feature that gets a branch...then it is merged back when stable.If I think I've hit a milestone or fixed something, I tag, correct ?

Comment: @wbg that sounds about right. You can define a feature as any new functionality, so pretty much the only things that don't get a branch is bug fixes or minor refactoring.

Comment: Thanks again...I'm reading the Pro Git pdf book which is good, but still required some clarifying questions. If I understand correctly, I should read about the different ways to merge in git. I'm curious about the squash wrt commits. Can you clarify for me a little more...:)